# How to remove empty elements from Dictionary<string,string>?

Tags: c#-4.0, dictionary

I'd like to remove all elements that have empty values from a Dictionary.  I've tried the following:

```
MyDict = MyDict.Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value));
```

But that throw the exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator' 1
[System.CollectionsGeneric.KeyVauePair' 2[System.String,System.String]]' to type
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' 2[System.String,System.String]'.
```

Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the assignment not in the Where call.

```
 MyDict = MyDict.Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value))
                .ToDictionary(i => i.Key);
```

Comment: Error: No overload for method 'ToDictionary' takes 0 arguments.

Comment: @4thSpace - there you go.

Comment: Thanks!  Now I'm getting an error that looks like this: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>'.  You have any idea about that.  The dictionary is defined as MyDict<string,string>.

Comment: @4thSpace I can't possibly help you unless you show me all the code, you said it is a dictionary, but this seems more complicated.  Add a function in the call to `ToDictionary()` to convert it.  `ToDictionary()` is well documented.

Comment: Isn't the ToDictionary(i => i.Key) function a Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.KeyValu‌​ePair<string,string>> type?  That doesn't convert into a Dictionary<string,string> right?

Comment: This is the one I need: .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value)

Answer (score 0):

`Where()` returns an `IEnumerable`. You need to call `.ToDictionary()` on the `IEnumerable` after you filter it to get a `Dictionary` back.